# How can i add select dropdown side of Mass action Button In Magento 2 Admin Side

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, drop-downs, select

I would like to get the select dropdown button on the side of Action Dropdown,for my custom grid collection at admin end, how can i achieve it,I would like to display the same dropdown beside. For more info please find the below screen shot.[image]
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Please check this link : https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-tree-into-mass-action-dropdown-in-backend/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the function below in your module block grid:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('post_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('post_ids');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
        'label'   => 'Delete',
        'url'     => $this->getUrl('*/post/massdelete'),
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
    ));
}
```

Comment: that function already exists @TZY

Answer (score 0):

You must create in your module a **UI** `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="your_action">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">your_action</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Action</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/product/yourAction"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

After created **UI**, you must create the controller `catalog/product/yourAction`